# Count number of letters in string (not characters, only letters)

Tags: python

I've tried looking for an answer but I'm only finding how to count the number of characters. I need to know how to count the number of letters within a string. Also need to know how to count the number of numbers in a string.

For example:

```
"abc 12"
```

the output would be

> letters: 3 
>   numbers: 2

Comment: I'd recommend implementing the solution for counting characters and trying to modify that to count only characters. You might be interested in `if in list()` . Once you have code that doesn't work add it to your question by editing and people will be more helpful. Welcome to S/O

Answer (score 5):

You have string methods for both cases. You can find out more on [string — Common string operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

```
s = "abc 12"

sum(map(str.isalpha, s))
# 3
sum(map(str.isnumeric, s))
# 2
```

---

Or using a generator comprehension with `sum`:

```
sum(i.isalpha() for i in s)
# 3
sum(i.isnumeric() for i in s)
# 2
```

Comment: If you wonder how `isalpha` works: `Alphabetic characters are those characters defined in the Unicode character database as “Letter”, i.e., those with general category property being one of “Lm”, “Lt”, “Lu”, “Ll”, or “Lo”.` So this is not limited to the Latin alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
s = 'abc 123'
len([c for c in s if c.isalpha()])
3
```

would work.

Also, since you `True` evaluates as 1 and `False` as 0, you can do:

```
sum(c.isalpha() for c in s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.isdigit()` which checks if a string(or character) contains only digits and `string.isalpha()` which checks if a string(or character) contains only characters  and do this

```
str='abc 123'
nums=len([char for char in str if char.isdigit()])
chars=len([char for char in str if char.isalpha()])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
s = 'abc 12'

p = [0 if c.isalpha() else 1 if c.isnumeric() else -1 for c in s]

letters, numeric = p.count(0), p.count(1)

print(letters, numeric)
```

output:

```
3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumming you are using Python 3.6+, I think using [generator expressions](https://dbader.org/blog/python-generator-expressions), the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function and a f-strings could solve your problem:

```py
>>> s = 'abc 12'
>>> numbers = sum(i.isnumeric() for i in s)
>>> letters = sum(i.isalpha() for i in s)
>>> f'letters: {letters} numbers: {numbers}'
'letters: 3 numbers: 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using **lambda** function with one line of code :)

```
counter = lambda word,TYPE: len([l for l in word if l.isalpha()]) if TYPE == str else len([n for n in word if n.isdigit()]) if TYPE == int else len([c for c in word if c.strip()]) if TYPE == all else TypeError("expected 'str' or 'int' or 'all' of 'TYPE' argument")

word = "abcd 123"

lettersCounter = counter(word, str) # >= 4
numbersCounter = counter(word, int) # >= 3
allCounter = counter(word, all) # >= 7
```